# Why state variables are declared with a const in useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In React 16's official documentation of `useState()` hook, the `count` state and its setter function is declared as:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

in the provided [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook).

My doubt is, why are they using **const** for a state variable, the value of which can be changed?

Comment: I guess because it shouldn't be changed in your code. You can only change count be calling setCount

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In React, you do not mutate the state variable directly.

In Class components, you'd never do `this.state.property = 'new value'` but use `this.setState({property: 'new value'})` to provide a new reference.

Same with hooks. you don't mutate the state value directly, like `count = 2`, but have to use `setCount(2)` to let React know that the state has been changed (and React can batch the state update as well).

If you'd like to to dig deeper check out the [official Reconciliation documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) on why React works this way. (hint: optimization).

Answer (score 0):

With

`const [count, setCount] = useState(0);`

You have a **copy** of the state variable, and the copy will not change even if you call `setCount`

Answer (score -1):

This isn't actually about React, but Flux.  Flux is a paradigm that involves stores of immutable states, with actions applied to a state to transform it to a new instance of immutable state.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but your answer is not addressing OP's question.

Comment: They are asking why they can't change the value of an immutable variable using a particular framework/library.  The framework/library (React) isn't actually the issue, it's the underlying state management paradigm that is being used by some framework/library extension (Redux).  The other answers don't address this, and conflate the DOM manipulation library (React) with the state management library (Redux).  So yeah, I am addressing the OPs question, and getting to the core of the issue far more than the other answers.

Comment: It's irrelevant to the framework, OP is asking about `const`.

Comment: "...why are they using const for a state variable, the value of which can be changed"  When using Flux, state is immutable, so you can safely use const.  This directly answers the question and the answer pertains to the state management paradigm.  Any alteration to the state would then be caught during development (assuming using strict), and would be a developer error when using Flux.

Comment: It's strictly a convention, OP could use `let` and even reassign `count` or `setCount` without any side-effects with the immutable state. It would be horrendous code smell, but it would work. OP was just confused with immutability, const and scoping, which your answer doesn't address.

Comment: This is a clear misunderstanding of how the underlying state management paradigm (Flux) operates, and trying to answer this question as though it is React specific is adding an unnecessary layer of abstraction, akin to answering a vanilla JS question using jQuery extensions.  The OP did not know Flux was what they were questioning, but it was.  It is good practice to declare semantic constants using `const`, because as you are implicitly acknowledging, we're dealing with a constant, because we're dealing with Flux -nothing to do with react other than react projects tend to use redux.

Comment: I don't think Flux is relevant here, even React doesn't mention Flux in their documentation. While the content of your answer isn't inherently false, it's unnecessarily confusing and a little off-track. OP is just using simple React hooks which are not Flux nor Redux though similar in their immutable unidirectional flow. OP could be asking why we're using `const` in `const num = Math.random()` and the answer would be the same, though _probabilistically_ different each time, it's never going to change within the function scope.

Comment: I agree though that it's unrelated to React, it's just the context that prompted OP to question why something that will change was declared as a `const`.